# Pdo inserting record multiple times, equal to database value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script that is working as far as selecting data, creating an array and inserting data (all using PDO). The only issue I'm having is that I need to modify how I do my inserts and updates.

Quite simply, each distinct record needs to be inserted in duplicate fashion (this sounds crazy, and I've brought that up to my team leader but the consensus is that we want every record to have their own date fields because only some will be updated). It sounds like it shouldn't be so difficult but I've never done something where I didn't use UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY or INSERT IGNORE. This is literally looking to duplicate certain records.

Basically this is all dependent on the `orqtyc AS QUANTITY` field in my first select.

I need to build several if statements, but the main issue is that  I first need to say something like ```WHILE insert count is < :QUANTITY, keep inserting until number of inserts equals :QUANTITY

Does that make sense? If not, I can clarify.

Basically I need help doing some logic to modify how I perform this already working insert. I can create the if/else statements I need but this is the first thing I need because any INSERT or UPDATE that's going to be done has to be equal to the quantity field for that order.

So basically for every record inserted, there should be 'n' number of records inserted. If record number 1 has quantity of 1, only insert 1. If record 2 has quantity of 10, insert that record 10 times.

```
$order_ids = [];
while ($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
}

if (count($order_ids) > 0) {
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($order_ids), '?'));
$detailStatCheck = "
    SELECT 
         invnoc as INVOICE,
         fstatc as STATUS,
         cstnoc AS DEALER,
         framec AS FRAME,
         covr1c AS COVER,
         colr1c AS COLOR ,
         extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
         orqtyc AS QUANTITY
    FROM GPORPCFL
    WHERE invnoc IN ($placeholders)
";

try {
    $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
    $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute($order_ids);
    $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
    print_r($order_ids);
    print_r($count2);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}


while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


 //IF exists and today is before expire date
 //update records = quantity, or insert

 //ELSEIF exists and today is  past expire_date, just insert number for each quantity

 //ELSE doesn't exist at all, perform below

$values = [
 ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
 ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
 ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
 ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
 ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
 ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
 ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
];


 $insertPlacement = "
 INSERT INTO placements_new (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date, locations, order_num)
 SELECT 
  id, 
  sku_group_id, 
  :DEALER, 
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as start_date,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, 
  :QUANTITY,
  :INVOICE  
FROM skus s  
  WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR
 ";
 try{
 $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
 $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
 }catch(PDOException $ex){
 echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: You cannot duplicate records (or entire rows) if you have unique fields in your table definition.  The way around this could be to add a new unique id to each row.  That id would be your primary key.  So you duplicate application data, but not the entire row.  Make that id an auto-increment so you do not need to specify it in your insert statements.  The database will take care of that.  For your limit (record 2 has quantity of 10), you will need to implement that in the application code.  Check how many you have already, then insert if quantity < max.

Comment: @Nic3500 right, sorry. I should have mentioned that I don't expect that but I don't have truly unique fields in the definition other than a primary key, but in my script I treat the sku_id/dealer_id as a unique index based on the date (that probably doesn't make sense). Anyway, this is just a way to give every order it's own record so I'm trying to find the easiest way to bypass a unique index

Answer (score 1):

So, I was overthinking this and adding an iterator for the QUANTITY value was the easiest way to go about it

```
 while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    //IF exists and today is before expire date
    //update records = quantity, or insert
    //ELSEIF exists and today is  past expire_date, just insert number for each quantity
    //ELSE doesn't exist at all, perform below

    $values = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];

    for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++) {

        try{
            $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```